# recursion and adding elements to an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to create an array of the first n primes starting with 2 in instance variable primes. I'm having two problems with this. One is figuring out what what should be happening in my base case in the countPrimes method. The other problem is figuring out how to add the elements or primes numbers into my array without any loops in my makeprimes method. If you have any advice that would be nice. For example if n was 10 it would produce:

```
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
```

My code is as follows:

```
private int[] primes = {};

public int[] getPrimes() {
    return primes;
}



public void countPrimes(int count, int n, int found) {
    if(n == found){
        //do nothing?
    }else if (isPrime(count) == true) {
        countPrimes(count + 1, n,found +1); 
    } else {
        countPrimes(count + 1,n,found);
    }
}

public void makePrimes(int n) {
    primes = new int[n];
    if(n>0){
        countPrimes(0,n,0);     
    }
}
```

Comment: In countPrimes, where do you add the prime numbers to the array? Also, do you have to do this recursively?

Comment: yes i do, and i did not i figured it would be better to add it in makePrimes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
public int[] makePrimes(int n){
    int[] primes = new int[n];
    return makePrimesHLP(n, primes, 2);

}

public int[] makePrimesHLP(int n, int[] primes, int pos, int numprimes){
    if(numprimes == n)
        return primes;
    if(isPrime(pos)){
        primes[numprimes] = pos;
        return makePrimesHLP(n, primes, ++pos, ++numprimes);
    }
    return makePrimesHLP(n, primes, ++pos, numprimes);
}
```

This is a pretty basic function (It goes through and checks if every single number is prime), but it should work (basic errors in my code withstanding).  You need to make sure you're returning something every time because otherwise you don't make progress.

Comment: There's no real reason to use `++` here, since you're not using those local variables afterward. You could simply a bit here by having a single `if/else` at the top level, and combining the second two parts, and making only the parts that depend on isPrime(pos) depend on it:  `if ( numprimes == n ) { return primes; } else { if ( isPrime(pos); ) { primes[numprimes++] = pos } return makePrimesHLP( n, primes, pos+1, numprimes ); }`

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Like I said, this is a pretty basic version of it just going over the structuring of recursion, making it as visible as possible as to what is happening.  As this looks like a homework assignment, I just want to give some framework to work with.